# How to set position for download popup control while playing videos?

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

I am trying to download video while playing in chrome browser, download, picture in picture are visible partially, these are far away from 3 dots(which are located @right end corner), I want to place it download, picture in picture popup at right end corner where I am clicking for these.

I try to change video frame width and height, based on video frame height these popup buttons are replacing but not useful for my requirement

I expect download, picture in picture popup buttons are near to right end corner of playing video while click on 3 dots(... ), actual is far away from 3dots(...)

here we can see after click on 3dots(...) download button is showing far away from 3Dots(...)

HTML:

```
<carousel class="video" interval="0">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let media of eventMedia">
    <slide *ngIf="media?.mediaType=='VIDEO'">
      <video 
        [authSrc]="media?.mediaURL" 
        [enableToken]="false" 
        [ngStyle]="{'width': '500px','height':'300px'}" 
        autoplay="false" 
        controls="true" 
        [muted]="true">
      </video>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <p>Camera {{media?.cameraNumber}}</p>
      </div>
      <a class="email col-md-12" 
         *ngIf="media?.mediaType == 'VIDEO'" 
         (click)="onEmailClick(eventMedia)" 
         title="Email media links">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope mailIcon"></i>
      </a>
    </slide>
  </ng-container>
</carousel>
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? Use stackblitz if necessary.

Comment: I added popup image for video,  you can see download button where it is placed

Comment: Okay, this should be some CSS issues. I think your box is not relative to your 3dots. For this we need your HTML implementation css styles for this box and dots.

Comment: <carousel class="video" interval="0"><ng-container  *ngFor="let media of eventMedia"><slide  *ngIf="media?.mediaType=='VIDEO'"><video [authSrc]="media?.mediaURL" [enableToken]="false" [ngStyle]="{'width': '500px','height':'300px'}" autoplay="false"
                controls="true" [muted]="true"></video><div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"><p>Camera {{media?.cameraNumber}}</p></div><a class="email col-md-12" *ngIf="media?.mediaType == 'VIDEO'" (click)="onEmailClick(eventMedia)" title="Email media links"><i class="fa fa-envelope mailIcon"></i></a></slide></ng-container></carousel>

Comment: The slider you are using is the problem. You could disable the video controls and create your own one, or you use another slider or you show us the full code in a stackblitz project. You could also check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039152/controlling-html5-video-within-slider